# Programmatically generated JSX string

Tags: reactjs

I have a text file that I'd like to convert to a JSX string using Regex and display on the browser as if it's a JSX markup manually entered in the render return () block.

Let's say I create a string

```
generatedString = '<span class="tag" style={divStyle}>Test string</span>'
```

and want to have it displayed in the browser by

```
render() {
  <div> {generatedString} <div>
}
```

The browser shows

```
"<span_class="tag"_style={divStyle}>Test string</span>"
```

as a text string, instead of "Test string" with the style applied to it.

Comment: You probably shouldn't need to go from JSX string to the DOM like that. If you elaborate on your use case, someone here might have a cleaner suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html) property on the div tag to render HTML as you like. This would still however be just displayed as HTML and not as a jsx tag, like this:

```
render() {
    return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={generatedString} />;
}
```

If you anyhow generate the JSX string yourself, then why not choose create a class that renders those properties, like in the following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/eLrfr2oh/3/)

```
var GeneratedComponent = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        content: React.PropTypes.object
    },
    render() {
        var content = this.props.content;
        if (!content || !content.tag) {
            return null;
        }
        return React.createElement(content.tag, content);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this as well.

Create a component that returns JSX and also takes the variables through props.

```
const renderSpan = ({divStyle}) => {
  return (
     <span class="tag" style={divStyle}>Test string</span>
  )
}
```

Then use it

```
<div>
  {renderSpan(divStyle)}
</div>
```

You can pass the divStyles as an object.