# How do I convert a string to React elements that can be rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have strings stored in a DB that are partial HTML, for example:

```
“Intro<br /><br />Paragraph 1<br /><br />Paragraph 2”
```

Say I want to render this string within a new `<p>` element, what is a simple way to accomplish this?

I am looking for a solution that doesn’t use an additional package and instead uses native JavaScript or a non-deprecated React function.

I am serving these string snippets to the React client, and I want React to eventually convert them from strings to HTML elements. However, doing so using `document.createElement` and manipulating the `innerHTML` of this new element gives me an error saying that Objects cannot be rendered in React. Say this new element is called `elem`, I am trying to render is like so:
`render(<div>{elem}</div>)`

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the string `“Intro<br /><br />Paragraph 1<br /><br />Paragraph 2”` is a string.  It is not JSX.  It does not get transposed into function calls for React elements.  So that string will simply be output to the DOM as a string, and that string will appear as text in the browser.

React uses a transpiling process to convert the JSX in your source code into JS function calls.  It does that during build-time.  The string in your database is not fetched until run-time, so there's no opportunity for the React build process to transpile it.

Lots of people have done things to "make this work" at runtime, but mostly those solutions are clunky and/or extremely dangerous, security-wise.

For example: [Programmatically generated JSX string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34841824/programmatically-generated-jsx-string?rq=4)

IMO the better approach would be for you to build some type of parser and/or simple Domain Specific Language (DSL) so that in your React code you are getting the data from the database, "interpreting" it, and dynamically rendering JSX.

For example, the above string could be processed as:

```js
const MyParserThingy = (props) => {

    const stringParts = props.inputString.split('<br />');
    let colorCounter = 0;

    return (<div>
        {stringParts.map((part) => {
           if(part.length > 0) {
             const theColor = (colorCounter++ % 2 === 0) ? 'red' : 'blue';
             return <p style={{color: theColor}}>{part}</p>;
           } else {
             return null;
           }
         })}
      </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById("root")
).render( <MyParserThingy inputString="Intro<br /><br />Paragraph 1<br /><br />Paragraph 2" />);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.0.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.0.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I totally hear you, and currently I am considering overhauling everything to implement SSR. But before I do I was curious if there was a "good" solution out there before I burn the whole system down.

Comment: I just added a simple "parser" example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can render it through  this method:

```
// Assuming you have the string stored in a variable named `htmlString`
const htmlString = "Intro<br /><br />Paragraph 1<br /><br />Paragraph 2";

// Create a new <p> element
const paragraph = document.createElement('p');

// Set the innerHTML of the <p> element to the HTML string
paragraph.innerHTML = htmlString;

// Now `paragraph` contains the parsed HTML content
// You can append it to the DOM wherever you want
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
```

**Another way in React**

```
import React from 'react';

const YourComponent = () => {
  // Assuming you have the string stored in a variable named `htmlString`
  const htmlString = "Intro<br /><br />Paragraph 1<br /><br />Paragraph 2";

  return (
    <div>
      {/* 
        Using dangerouslySetInnerHTML to set the HTML content 
        Make sure the HTML content is safe and trusted 
      */}
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlString }}></p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Comment: The "dangerously..." is React letting you know: "THIS IS NOT A GOOD IDEA".

Comment: You lost me on the last two lines of code. What is `Create`, and what is `paragraph`? These elements came out of nowhere.

Comment: I think he meant, pTag instead of Create and pTag instead of paragraph as well

Comment: It's a mistake in the code I suppose.

Comment: @GregFenton While there are certainly valid use cases for dangerouslySetInnerHTML, such as rendering trusted content from known sources, it's crucial to be mindful of the security implications and ensure that the HTML content being inserted is safe and properly sanitized to mitigate the risk of XSS vulnerabilities.

Comment: @iamsmruti I see which are you asking about I will update it. Thanks

Comment: I stand by my original statement :)

Comment: @AliAsad not sure it was necessary to point out to @ GregFenton the security risks of manipulating the DOM like this, he basically started his post by saying that